# Vim autocmd inoremap works wrong when just single character in "<>"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, autocmd

I've been using vim to write html files recently.

I'm so sick of the `<...>` and `<\...>`, so I write some `inoremap` for convenience in a vim file:

```
autocmd Filetype html inoremap <buffer> <c-i> <><Esc>i
autocmd Filetype html inoremap <buffer> <c-j> <Esc>vi>"xyo<\<Esc>"xpa><Esc>O
autocmd Filetype html inoremap <buffer> <c-l> <Esc>vi>"xyf>a<\<Esc>"xpa><Esc>F<i
```

I edit a temporary html file to test it. Everything works fine but when I type `<C-i> a <C-l>`. I thought the result would be `<a> <\a>`, **but it stopped in visual mode, selecting the `a`, it feels like it just executed `<Esc>vi>` and **stopped**.**

After many tries, I realized that as long as there is **only one character** in `<` `>`, it works wrong.

I try split the command into

```
autocmd Filetype html inoremap <buffer> <c-t> <Esc>vi>
autocmd Filetype html noremap  <buffer> <c-y> "xyf>a<\<Esc>"xpa><Esc>F<i
```

It works.

Is there any hidden problem with vim's visual mode or my vim?

Comment: Your `<C-i>` and `<C-l>` mappings seem to work fine, here. I suggest you remove the others from your question as they are irrelevant.

Comment: It works fine in my manjaro computer. It's maybe my windows's problem, should I delete this question ?

Comment: Well, you can keep it open and mention that Manjaro vs Windows discrepancy.

Comment: Latest discovery, after I upgrade my gvim to 9.0 the problem solved. I used 8.2 before, this question may be a bit too coincidental.